# Terraform template_file vars attribute getting defined

Tags: terraform

I have a module with a template_file section including vars, where the vars are used in a subsequent resource

```
data "template_file" "my_template" {
   template = "/dev/null"
   vars {
      var1 = "value with ${var.module_input}"
   }
}

resource .... {
  attribute = "${data.template_file.my_template.vars.var1}"
}
```

When I run `terraform` I get an error like

```
Resource 'data.template_file.my_template' does not have attribute 'vars.var1' for variable 'data.template_file.my_template.vars.var1'
```

It looks like, for whatever reason, `var1` in the template vars is not getting defined and available for subsequent use.

How would I troubleshoot what might have caused individual variables to not be exported from `template_file`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't set the template var value in a local and then reuse it later?

Comment: I agree that would be better, but it's not my own module.

Answer (score 0):

template_file exposes vars as a map.

You'd need to do

`attribute = "${data.template_file.my_template.vars['var1']}"`

to access it.

You can read about this here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#user-map-variables